# Serving multiple web apps in same IP different Ports with Apache2

Tags: virtualhost, unix, apache2, web-hosting

I have multiple web project in the same VPS as below:

```
/var/www/html/
│---webapp1/
│   │---public/
│   │   │---index.php
│---webapp2/
│   │---public/
│   │   │---index.php
│---index.html
```

I want to serve the `webapp1` under `95.87.154.170:81` and `webapp2` under `95.87.154.170:87`.

I have tried to create virtual hosts `/etc/apache2/sites-available/webapp1.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/webapp1

    <Directory /var/www/html/webapp1>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
     </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/webapp2.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:87>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/webapp2

    <Directory /var/www/html/webapp2>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
     </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work when I visit `95.87.154.170:81` or `95.87.154.170:87` it shows `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. Both sites are enabled. My problem is I have only one IP and I don't have domain names. Is there any possibility to solve it in this way?

Comment: Define `doesn't work`. The actual error message tells a lot about where the problem could be. Apart from that, get a domain. It costs next to nothing and allows you to use subdomains for the applications, so you don't have to meddle with different ports.

Comment: One thing that stands you: you write that you created the config files in `sites-available`. In debian based systems this directory is only used indirectly. You need to create symlinks in `sites-enabled` to files in that dir (usually using `a2ensite webapp1; a2ensite webapp2; systemctl reload apache`).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, Yes I did it.

Comment: Did you configure apache to listen on these ports?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, nope just did it works fine!

Comment: Go and buy a domain name.

Comment: @lucifer, if you have solved your problem, please post your solution in an answer below. It will help others who come across your question.